# Slim Framework: Route only accepted parameters

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I want to define two routes based on route parameters, for example:

```
$app->get('/{param}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
  // This route can only accept params like: colors, finish, material
}

// And to have another similar but to accept different params

$app->get('/{param2}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
  // This route can only accept params like: jobs, customers
}
```

I can check which param it is in route callbacks, but I don't think in this situation both route callbacks are being invoked, right? i.e I can check that in the first route, but the callback for the second route will not be invoked.

Is there something I can add to the get object to fulfill what I want?

Comment: Are `colors, finish, material` and `jobs, customers` all the acceptable words for `param` and `param2`? If not, please give more details about *exactly* what words are acceptable for each route.

Comment: No, `colors, finish and material` is acceptable only for `param`, and `jobs and customers` is acceptable only for `param2`

Comment: You can not define two routes having the patterns like yours. An exception of type `FastRoute\BadRouteException` is thrown: _"Cannot register two routes matching "/([^/]+)" for method "GET"_. This is triggered by the call `RegexBasedAbstract::addVariableRoute` when trying to add the second route in `Router::createDispatcher`.

Comment: That said, the only option I can think of is to define only one route (like your first one, for example) which allows inputing all values, but to filter/validate the given values of the parameters - inside the closure - by certain conditions/data structures, defined by you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define route params in a way to match certain patterns. In your case, this patterns are predefined set of words:

```
$app->get('/{param:colors|finish|materials}', function ( $request, $response, $args) {
  // This route can only accept params like: colors, finish, material
    return "First route with param: " . $args['param'];
});

// And having another route similar but to another params

$app->get('/{param:jobs|customers}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  // This route can only accept params like: jobs, customers
    return "Second route with param: " . $args['param'];
});
```

You can read more about route patterns in [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) documentation.

Comment: This solution looks very good, I need to test. Also, are you sure that package works with slim? A little review on their documentation and didn't found any mention to slim framework.

Comment: Slim router is built on this package, it is mentioned here https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html